# The network connection was lost when calling PHP API

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
    var SubmitDic = NSMutableDictionary ()
    SubmitDic.setObject (loginMerged, forKey: "module" )
    SubmitDic.setObject (kedahE-tutorApp, forKey: "wsKey" )
    SubmitDic.setObject (112211, forKey: "passwd" )
    SubmitDic.setObject (form04, forKey: "userName" )

    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: http://kedah-etutor.com/component/module/ws_function2.php)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(SubmitDic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions() , error: nil)
    println(NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(SubmitDic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions() , error: nil)?.description)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error : AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil

        if data != nil
        {
        }
```

I have tried to call the  php json web service, however it returns null data and the error description keep mention about "The network connection was lost". Besides, in Java HttpClient framework works well with the PHP web services.

Comment: Always check for all potential errors: `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` returns an Optional - that is, it might be `nil` indicating an error.

Comment: i get this when print the dataWithJSONObject, 

Optional("<7b227773 4b657922 3a226b65 64616845 2d747574 6f724170 70222c22 6d6f6475 6c65223a 226c6f67 696e4d65 72676564 222c2275 7365724e 616d6522 3a22666f 726d3034 222c2270 61737377 64223a22 31313232 3131227d>")

it means error occured ?